# Application to watch what an executable does?

Tags: windows, process, monitoring

I need to find out exactly what files/directories a Lua program uses so I can try to only pack what it needs into a ZIP file, and come up with a simple way to deploy this script.

I used SysInternals' [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), but I'm surprised by the small amount of information it returned while it watched the program (For Lua users out there, it's [wsapi.exe](http://keplerproject.github.com/wsapi/manual.html), which is the launcher for the light-weight Xavante web server).

Does someone know of a good Windows application that can completely monitor what a program does, eg. something like a live version of the venerable PCMag's InCtrl5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Process monitor will catch everything.  If it's not catching the action then it must be happening in a different process.  Try filtering based on the files you expect to be used rather than the process you expect it to happen in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After modifying the filter, I did see some entries related to the Lua program I needed to watch.